# mysql query from 1st domain and insert in 2nd domain

Tags: php, mysql

i have data in one of my website and i want to insert these data in other site.these two are in same server.at present i have to export mysql data and import into other then do this code to insert in 2nd domain.

i want to link directly so that i can make data request from 1st website and insert into 2nd website.

i know for this to happen i need to enable bind-address     = 127.0.0.1 to ip address of server and i have changed this

here is my code.

databaseconnect.php

```
 <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","UserA","passwordA","databaseA");


 if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
   ?>
```

here is my insert code  which works if database is imported in website2 and run.but i want to avoid this manual work and want to link two database of different website as its on my server and i have full control on both
this code is in website2.

insert.php

```
        <?
        include('/home/website2/public_html/databaseconnect.php'); 
        $res2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `website1_tableA`  where status='0' order by id asc limit 30");
        while($result = $res2->fetch_assoc()){
        $cont=$result['content'];
        $tit=$result['title'];
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO website2_tableB (content,title) VALUES ('$cont','$tit')");
        }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use 2 connections if you understand that you have to?

```
<?php
$con  = new mysqli("localhost","UserA","passwordA","databaseA");
$con2 = new mysqli("localhost","UserA","passwordA","databaseB");

$res = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `website1_tableA`  where status='0' order by id asc limit 30");

while($result = $res->fetch_assoc())
{
    $cont=$result['content'];
    $tit=$result['title'];
    $con2->query("INSERT INTO website2_tableB (content,title) VALUES ('$cont','$tit')");
}
```

Comment: i understand that first connection will be localhost but second connection will be localhost?

Comment: yeah, you'll stay alive if you use it

Comment: localhost is an adress of your mysql server, username and password can be the same too

Comment: Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user

Answer (score 0):

You used "$con" as class on insert.php, while it isn't defined as class on databaseconnect.php.

Try changing databaseconnect.php like that:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost","UserA","passwordA","databaseA");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>
```

and insert.php like that (I've changed just the last line):

```
<?
include('/home/website2/public_html/databaseconnect.php'); 
$res2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `website1_tableA`  where status='0' order by id asc limit 30");
while($result = $res2->fetch_assoc()){
$cont=$result['content'];
$tit=$result['title'];
$con->query("INSERT INTO website2_tableB (content,title) VALUES ('$cont','$tit')");
}

?>
```

Hope that'll work :)

Comment: how it will work?? i dont think so. the connection details for insert will be different as it is other website.how to use that